# I get error CORS when I added UserManager

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cors

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000//register' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I added in constructor UserManager and SignInManager. Then I get error.

Controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class AccountController : BaseController
{
  List<User> users = new List<User>
    {
        new User { Login="admin", Password="12345", Role = "admin" },
        new User { Login="qwerty", Password="55555", Role = "user" }
    };

  public AccountController(IOptions<AWSEmailCredentials> options, UserManager<User> userManager, SignInManager<User> signInManager)
  {    }

  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Register([FromBody] User user)
  {
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
    }
  }
}
```

Startup:

```
public class Startup
{
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
  Configuration = configuration;
}

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddCors(options =>
  {
    options.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin",
        builder => builder.AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyOrigin());
  });

  services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
  {
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
    {
      ValidateIssuer = true,
      ValidIssuer = AuthOptions.ISSUER,
      ValidateAudience = true,
      ValidAudience = AuthOptions.AUDIENCE,
      ValidateLifetime = true,

      IssuerSigningKey = AuthOptions.GetSymmetricSecurityKey(),
      ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
    };
  });

  services.AddRouting();
  services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

  services.Configure<AWSCredentials>(Configuration.GetSection("AWSCredentials"));
  services.Configure<AWSEmailCredentials>(Configuration.GetSection("AWSEmailCredentials"));

  services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<DAL.ApplicationContext>();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
  if (env.IsDevelopment())
  {
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
  }
  else
  {
    app.UseHsts();
  }

  app.UseCors("AllowOrigin");
  app.UseHttpsRedirection();
  app.UseStaticFiles();

  app.UseAuthentication();

  app.UseMvc();
}
```

}

User:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Login { get; set; }
  public string Password { get; set; }
  public string Role { get; set; }
  public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext:

```
public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }

public ApplicationContext()
{
  Database.EnsureCreated();
}

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
  if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
  {
    optionsBuilder
        .UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=Books;User id=xx;Password=xxx;");
  }
}
}
```

Help me please resolve this problem.

Comment: Your cors issue is nothing to do with adding a `UserManager` into your DI container. Check your UI to see what is trying to send a request to that url.

Comment: I don't see how adding identity would cause a CORS error.

Comment: Adding identity causes a CORS error when you are using a reverse proxy.  For example if you are using .NET COre behind nginx or other webserver.   asp.net core runs from a server called kestrel and when you put it behind a reverse proxy core application understands different headers.  for identity to work you will need to forward the headers and accept those headers in your startup file.

Comment: If you explain to me more about your setup I might be able to help you.

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? Maybe what happened ism your code changes caused an error & now instead of the server sending a 200 OK response, it’s sending a 4xx or 5xx error. If so, it’s expected the 4xx or 5xx error wouldn’t have an Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header, because most servers by default don’t add application-set response headers to 4xx or 5xx errors—instead servers only add them to 2xx success responses. If in fact you’re getting a 4xx or 5xx response, then you should check the server logs to see what messages the server is logging to indicate the cause

Comment: @Darkonekt, I added classes Startup and controller. Server - .Net Core 2.1. Client - Angular 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added class:

```
public class IdentityContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
  public IdentityContext(DbContextOptions<IdentityContext> options)
      : base(options) { }

  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
  {
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
  }
}
```

And in Startup:

```
services.AddDbContext<IdentityContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<DAL.IdentityContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Comment: did this fix the CORS error? Does not sound like it

Comment: It's completely unclear how this would affect CORS.

Comment: It looks like it was an internal error, but it caused a CORS error.